# Hiding the JQL Query for the search filters

Tags: filter, jira, jira-filter

I have created a search filter for the tickets updated within a day. 
And the query looks like:

> updated >= -1d ORDER BY created DESC

I want to hide the query behind the filter for logged in users other then the owner

Answer (score 1):

1. Save this filter.
2. Create another one filter with JQL:

   filter = id_of_filter_from_step_1

   filter = 14811 (for example)

Not sure is it helps after all, but you can at least sort of hide it. Unfortunately that doesn't change that users still need access from you first filter. So, they will be able to take id, place it to url https://your_jira_url/issues/?filter=### and get original JQL request.

As far as I know you can't hide JQL request by way it described in question.

Answer (score 1):

When you save a filter in Jira, by default it is visible only to you. You don't need to additionally hide it.

Comment: But i want to be  shared with others so that they use the filter. But i don't want the JQL to be visible to others except me or the owner.